# How do I create a fluid vortex/whirlpool?

Tags: fluid-simulation

This questions has been asked before but never satisfactorily answered...
I'm looking to create something like this...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCjCQwgcXHg

As you can see, its liquid so I don't want to use particles.

I've tried spinning an object as in the youtube. Not great results... any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks